# Migrating from Starter to Enterprise(Small)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have developed an enterprise level chatting app on android platform which is live now to users,by using quickblox SDK 2.5.2 in starter tier. I am planning to upgrade to dedicated instance of quickblox (Small). Please let me know the setup procedure and other details including downtime during up scaling  of the instance. Also do let me know the changes i need to do in my app and if any other places required.

**if i wanted to migrate what are the changes required?**
 
    In terms of setup procedure and other details including downtime during up scaling  of the instance.

**Also do let me know the changes i need to do in my app and if any other places required.**

what will be required things i need to do in case :
 
i.  i use own server for hosting
 
ii. i use AWS infrastructure managed by QuickBlox team for hosting

Answer (score 1):

You can reach out to the QB support team, and they can walk you through all the  steps in migration to enterprise. The team is very helpful and quick.

1. You will need an AWS server to host
2. Sign the contracts to setup your account
3. Pay for the service

Please note, that after you migrate you won't be able to roll back.